# PHP MySQL item categories

Tags: php, mysql, categories

I'm trying to display a list of items with their name and all categories they belong to.

My database structure is:

```
Items table with Id, Item_Name.
Categories table with Id, Category_Name
Items_Categories table with Id, Item_id, Category_id.
```

I'd like to display the results in a table with the Item Name, and a comma-delimited list of its Categories' Names. I'm not sure how to do this with a single query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at group_concat(). Beware at its max length.

Comment: Maybe you should do some research, you won't learn anything if we do the work for you. There's loads of php/mysql tutorials over at http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/

Comment: +1 @nick for mentioning max length - it's caught me before..

Comment: Thanks everyone. That was way easier than I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `GROUP_CONCAT` function that is available in mysql:

```
select i.item_name, group_concat(c.category_name) as categories
from items i
inner join items_categories ic on i.id = ic.item_id
inner join categories c on ic.category_id = c.id
group by i.item_name
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't write it for you, but you need to use group_concat() function (MySQL).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT i.Item_Name, GROUP_CONCAT(c.Category_Name) AS Category_List
FROM Items AS i
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  Items_Categories AS ic 
  INNER JOIN Categories AS c ON ic.Category_id = c.Id
) ON i.Id = ic.Item_id
GROUP BY i.Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I must say I did not test this query, but it should be something similar to the following:

```
SELECT i.Id, i.Item_name, GROUP_CONCAT(c.Category_Name) AS category_list
FROM Items i
JOIN Items_categories ci ON ci.Item_id = i.Id
LEFT JOIN Categories c ON c.Id = ci.Id
GROUP BY i.Id
```

Note that you can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to create a comma seperated list.